# Validating Azure AD ID Token on Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a Web API running on .NET and a React Front-End. Using Azure AD and MSAL I was able to secure the front-end with SSO as well as the back-end. When the user sign's on I can see there is a "Id Token" in the cookies.

Is there a way to pass the ID token from the front-end to the back-end and validate the token before I return my API results?

Answer (score 1):

To configure how to return id token from  Azure Ad.Please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app#enable-implicit-grant-flow).[image]

The `id_tokens` are sent to the client application as part of an OpenID Connect (OIDC) flow.

To validate id token in web API please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#token-validation)

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_1M7sVnVkyGZXF0p&Q_CHL=gl
>